# Visual Studio 2013 hanging on getting latest from TFS

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs, team-explorer

In my Visual Studio 2013 I'm trying to get the latest version of a project from TFS but this hangs on until the timeout error occurs.

I've tried deleting the Team Explorer cache a couple of times, undo all the changes, restart, rebuild but still the same issue.

What's even more interesting is that there someone else in my team with a similar version of Visual Studio that hangs when getting the latest on the same project.

We're using VSO so I was expecting this will not have issues.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Andrei

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure if you are running antivirus that your work space is excluded from the rules. Otherwise it has to check each and every file which is a major slow down. Also check your local work space to see if the files are getting copied. Check the event log on the TFS server it may have a reason. Also try using the VS command line to make the same request.